# Rails how to store passwords for other services?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What is the safest way of storing passwords that is used to other services?

Example:

App that needs to store passwords for other sites to do a rake task for fetching data that require authentication.

Comment: In an encrypted file.

Answer (score 2):

You would store this data as environment variables. For example, for one of my projects I need my app to have access to a Github login. This Github login is stored as an environment variable by adding the following line to my .bashrc file.

```
export GITHUB_LOGIN=myLogin
```

In my app's config file I refer to this environment variable like this:

```
:github_login: <%= ENV['GITHUB_LOGIN'] %>
```

This config file is then loaded by the app like this:

```
require 'erb'
raw_data = File.read(config_file)
erbified_data = ERB.new(raw_data).result
```

Comment: +1 - This will work so long as you only need one set of credentials (e.g. not one username/password for **every user** of the app).

Comment: What about storing a salt in a enviroment variable and then encrypt the passwords with it when it is stored in the database and used it to decrypt when using it in the rake task..